# Accumulator Loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Create a function called `totalSales()`. The function will use a loop to ask the user to enter amounts until they enter the word "done". The body of the loop will add the input amount to a variable called totalSales. When the loop ends the function should display the value of totalSales in an alert.

Here's what I have...

```
function totalSales()
{
     var x = prompt("Enter numeric until done")
     var amount="";
     var totalSales=0;

     while(x!=="done") { 
         x = prompt("Enter numeric until done") 

         if(x==="done")
         {
             alert(totalSales += amount);       
         } 
     }  
 }
```

My onclick event handler works but I'm not sure how to add an unknown number to a variable. I cannot get it to add instead of concatenate.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) function to convert the string value to an integer value.

```
function totalSales()
{
   var x = prompt("Enter numeric until done")
   var amount = "";
   var totalSales = 0;

   while(x!=="done")
   { 
        x = prompt("Enter numeric until done");

        if(x==="done")
        {
            alert(totalSales);
        } 
        else if(!isNaN(x)) 
        {
            totalSales += parseInt(x, 10);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It's good practice to always specify base 10 when using `parseInt`; otherwise you'll get weird results if someone enters something like `010` (you get 8 because that's an octal literal).

Comment: I added it, but I believe that `parseInt` ignores the leading 0

Comment: `parseInt()` mostly doesn't try and guess the radix now I believe (in browsers).

Comment: Yeah, `parseInt("010")` will return 10 while `parseInt("0xF")` will return 15. So it will recognise hex but ignores octal.

Comment: The behavior of parseInt varies if you are using an `ES3` or `ES5` browser, so both comments are correct.  Still good practice to keep this in mind because it *will* bite (or should that be byte you) should you forget.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize the behavior was corrected in the ES5 spec. Still a good practice when you can't guarantee that people aren't still using IE 7 or worse.